# Zapier integration with long running tasks not response data

Tags: zapier

I have a Zapier Integration in which some actions (requests to my backend) require more time to respond (up to one minute), and when I'm testing a new Zap with this action I'm receiving a "No data" in the response result.
Here is my action code

```
    key: "prediction",
    noun: "Prediction",
    display: {
        label: "Create Prediction",
        description: "Creates a new prediction.",
    },
    operation: {
        inputFields: [
            {
                key: "question",
                required: true,
                type: "string",
                helpText: 'Provide a "Yes" or "No" question to ask the Magic 8-Ball.',
            },
        ],
        perform: async (z, bundle) => {
            const promise = await z.request({
                url: "https://e448-38-54-105-8.ngrok.io/v1/zapier/test",
                method: "POST",
                body: {
                    url: z.generateCallbackUrl(),
                },
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "X-API-Key": "secret",
                },
            });
            return { hello: "world" };
        },
        performResume: (z, bundle) => {
            return { ...bundle.outputData, ...bundle.cleanedRequest };
        },
    },
};
```

My backend post method code:

````
  async testCallback(@Body('url') url) {
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }),
    });
  }```

I need to receive data from my backend long running tasks and I'm trying to use [GenerateCallbackUrl](https://platform.zapier.com/reference/cli-docs#zgeneratecallbackurl) but it doesn't response my data.
````